# c# limit decimal value to 2 places

Tags: c#, string, winforms, decimal

I found a ton of answers but none work for me, can anyone help me with this problem.
I have a formula witch gives a very extensive result and only want a value like for instance 1,25

I tried several codes but none worked, what i have now is:

```
    uw = (adp * ufa + adv * ug + perv * wmk) / ac;
    String.Format("{0:.##}", uw);
    resposta.Text = uw.ToString();
```

`resposta` is a `label` in witch i display the answer.
`uw` is `decimal`.

I dont want to round the value, just limit the numbers.

Thansk for the assist,

Comment: Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @VivekVerma: _"I dont want to round the value, just limit the numbers"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work if you are OK with rounding:

```
uw = (adp * ufa + adv * ug + perv * wmk) / ac;
resposta.Text = uw.ToString("N2");
```

This should work if you don't want to round values:

```
uw = (adp * ufa + adv * ug + perv * wmk) / ac;
resposta.Text = (Math.Truncate(uw * 100) / 100).ToString();
```